# simultaneously call multiple Api request in spring mvc

Tags: spring, rest, spring-mvc

My requirement is, I have to call multiple API in my REST application . I want each API will work independently irrespective of waiting for response from the other. i.e I need if one API request take 5sec then all the api request should take 5sec also

Answer (score 0):

You can make the `API` call inside a seperate thread as shown below:

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
public void run() {
try {
// Do your api call here
}
catch(Exception e)
{// Log or do watever you need}
}
```

Thus the API call will work `asynchronously` !

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **org.springframework.web.client.AsyncRestTemplate** class which return a ListenableFuture to get the value asynchronously. So your method will have take time equal to the most slowest api call.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    AsyncRestTemplate asycTemp = new AsyncRestTemplate();
    HttpMethod method = HttpMethod.GET;
    // create request entity using HttpHeaders
    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.setContentType(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN);
    HttpEntity<String> requestEntity = new HttpEntity<String>("params", headers);
    ListenableFuture<ResponseEntity<String>> future = asycTemp.exchange("https://www.google.com", method, requestEntity, String.class);
    ListenableFuture<ResponseEntity<String>> future1 = asycTemp.exchange("https://www.yahoo.com", method, requestEntity, String.class);
    ListenableFuture<ResponseEntity<String>> future2 = asycTemp.exchange("https://www.bing.com", method, requestEntity, String.class);
    try {
        // waits for the result
        ResponseEntity<String> entity = future.get();
        // prints body source code for the given URL
        System.out.println(entity.getBody());
        entity = future1.get();
        System.out.println(entity.getBody());
        entity = future2.get();
        System.out.println(entity.getBody());
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ExecutionException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```